# How do you show expected values of react component props in vscode?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, material-ui, intellisense, react-proptypes

I am trying to create my own private component library. I manage to show the description of the prop using prop-types but the expected values are not shown. I haven't seen any documentation regarding this one or I'm just blind.

This is what I'm trying to achieve just like in material-UI.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PropTypes` is for runtime checks it has nothing to do with VSCode auto-complete/auto-suggestions.

Getting a description of the property is a part of VSCode, it gets it from function parameters:

```
// Will get those props autocomplete
const Component = ({ prop1, prop2, prop3 }) => {}

// Won't get autocomplete
const Component = (props) => {}
```

For getting **auto-suggestion** you need to add types for the component or using types system like Typescript and Flow.

See [types example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.d.ts) in Material UI repo.

See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194059/how-to-configure-types-in-javascript-file-for-getting-auto-suggestion/62194786#62194786) of how it's done.

Comment: Thank you, i thought auto-suggestion might be easier. i'll try though.

Comment: @vexingCoder If you wonder how its done, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62194059/how-to-configure-types-in-javascript-file-for-getting-auto-suggestion/62194786#62194786

Comment: you sir is just amazing, i remove index.d.ts and it worked. if i wanted to use index.d.ts just for organization how do i go about it? [working image](https://imgur.com/a/6X8If81)

Comment: Sorry I have little knowledge about it, better ask the community

Answer (score 3):

I really appreciate what @dennis-vesh said. However this method will give you ability to suggest options like MaterialUI does. Suppose you have a prop named as `type`. The types are `facebook`, `youtube` and `twitter`. Now you want your component should suggest it to the developer when they use your component. The method helps me most is `JSDOC` method.

```js
/**
 * 
 * @param {{ 
 * type: "facebook" | "youtube" | "twitter";
 * }} props Props for the component
 * 
 */
const Component({ type }) => {....}
```

[image: VS code suggestion screenshot]