# How to configure types in JavaScript file for getting auto-suggestion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

What should one configure for getting auto-suggestions (with types) in the Javascript file?

> In other words, given a component written in JS, how to get auto-suggestion of its props (it is possible, please read all the question).

I'm trying to get auto-suggestion for a simple Button component (to get a suggestion of "red" or "blue"), [similar to components in MUI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.d.ts?fbclid=IwAR2VrSz5RVgOr7W8dfmtv0sKBVfYi1uDfm8alVrqUOGv7Sh8tUTXfmKnM1s).

```
// Would like the IDE so suggest "red" or "blue" on changing color prop
const App = () => {
  return <Button color="red" />;
};
```

```
// Button.js
import React from "react";

const Button = ({ color }) => <button style={{ color }}>Button</button>;

export default Button;
```

```
// ButtonTypes.d.ts
export interface Button {
  color: "red" | "blue";
}
```

[image: Edit Button with types]

Comment: Javascript does not have types, your IDE cannot  know the type of a variable without the type annotation.

Comment: Which IDE? There are literally thousands of them.

Comment: How the IDE matters? TS types are not constricted to IDE. Here is an example from [other source](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-with-types-1vmx2?file=%2Fsrc%2FButton.js&fbclid=IwAR12WMxdQL-YkLq5l5HEU9ILQDgIXF_lFG141QF7VcKnWMBF-5sRkz2ys0g) trying to answer this question.

Comment: Example VS Code have own TS https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript

Comment: The IDE matters because each implements "autosuggestions" differently, if at all. There is no requirement that they implement the feature.

Comment: The IDE doesn't matter, there is an integration file for TS but the typescript types auto-completion not related. I use VSCode, wonder how it will differ the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See changes [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/button-with-types-if07g).

```
// Button.d.ts
import * as React from "react";

declare const Button: React.FC<{
  color: "red" | "blue";
}>;

export default Button;

// App.js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {/* Auto-suggests "red" and "blue" */}
      <Button color="red" />
    </>
  );
};
```

You need to name the `.d.ts` file with the same name as the `.js`. Also, you need you declare the `Button`, not just the props.

Comment: Thank you ben, nicely done. Does `index.d.ts` file is useless?

Comment: @DennisVash yes, it's unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

Although [@bengr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62194380/7882470) given a great answer, there is an alternative using Typescript in JSDocs, it allows semantic errors in javascript files:

```
// App.js

// @ts-check
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Button color="red" />
      {/* Shows a WARNING! */}
      <Button color={null} />
    </>
  );
};

// types.ts
import type { CSSProperties, FunctionComponent } from "react";

export type ButtonComponent = FunctionComponent<{color: CSSProperties["color"]}>;

// Button.js
import React from "react";

/**
 * @type {import("./types").ButtonComponent}
 */
const Button = ({ color }) => <button style={{ color }}>Button</button>;

export default Button;
```

[image: Edit Button with types]